# Outlook rest api 2.0 in a Windows Service built using C#

Tags: c#, rest, outlook, windows-services

I've got a working Windows Service built using C# and using Outlook REST API 1 that reads a mailbox to extract attachments from messages.

It works well... but Microsoft decided to deprecate and stop this API.

Now I try to use API 2.0, but I'm not able to authenticate to the API using user / password as I was doing using API 1.

If I anderstand how it works using API 2.0, I can :
- Get a token using Application Id / Secure key, But in this case, I won't be able to get messages as a specific user.
- Get a token using user Id / password, but in this case, these informations will be filled by a user into Wicrosoft web connection form.

The first one is compatible with web services, but I can't do what I want.
The second allows me to do what I want, but it is not compatible with Windows service.

Am I right ?
Is there another option to achieve my goal ?

Thanks for advance,

Comment: Yes,  Microsoft recommends using Microsoft Graph to access Outlook mail, calendar, and contacts.
Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message

Comment: Yes, but using Graph or Outlook rest API 2.0 drives me to the same authentication issue, isn't it ?